# session not working in Yii after uploading the backup files - exception.CHttpException.404

Tags: session, yii

We are facing a strange issue in your web app developed in Yii.
Our files were stored under /storage-pool and it was linked from /var/www/html. Today we found that the server shows a 503 error, and the folder storage-pool had permissions like ??????. Hence we uploaded our weekly backup to the main folder under /var/www/html

We uploaded the files as root and later we changed the entire folders and files under the group www-data and owner as www-data.

The log file give - "exception.CHttpException.404"
the file name and the line # is - core/web/CWebApplication.php:286

Now the issue is that sessions are not working in the site. 
Can any one help me out on this?

Only sessions are not working inside the Yii app. I tried to login using cookies and found it redirecting to the other page.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got it working once i restarted the server. 
I think once the folder storage-pool got corrupted, i mounted it again, but a system restart was needed.
Once done, everything is working fine!